# How to Dockerize node+postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm pretty new to Docker and I was asked to write an api with node, express and postgres and dockerize it.

I created the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./ 
RUN npm install
COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "npm run migrate up && npm start"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://root:password@db:5432/chargeflow
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=chargeflow
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

But when i build the docker-compose is get this errors/warnings:

```
app_1  | 
app_1  | > chargeflow-postgres@1.0.0 migrate /app
app_1  | > node-pg-migrate "up"
app_1  | 
app_1  | Can't determine timestamp for 20210128200430-create-tweet
app_1  | Can't determine timestamp for 20210128200611-create-like
app_1  | Can't determine timestamp for 20210128200656-create-re-tweet
app_1  | > Migrating files:
app_1  | > - 20210128200430-create-tweet
app_1  | > - 20210128200611-create-like
app_1  | > - 20210128200656-create-re-tweet
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: All those errors come from your app, so we have no idea. You need to refocus and find a minimal reproduction.

Comment: But locally (without Docker) it works perfect.. so i don’t know what’s wrong:(

Comment: Why is the output you've shown wrong?  What's it supposed to do?  Without seeing any of your code, it looks like you're asking it to run migrations, and it is.

Comment: Ok. I removed the migration option, but now i get this ERROR:
`app_1  | (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`

Comment: Maybe the postgresql is not fully started when the node tries to communicate. You can try to stop your local postgresql, start the postgresql docker image with the configuration in the compose file and start your LOCAL nodejs and check if it connects properly